# Не удалось извлечь метаданные для модели

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Всем привет. Создал по шаблону `asp.net mvc` проект с системой `identity`.

Добавил две модели: жанр и игра (`Genre` & `Game`)

```
// Класс - жанр игры
public class Genre
{
    [Key] // первичный ключ
    public int GenreId { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; } // название жанра

    // Конструктор с параметром
    public Genre(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    } // Genre
} // Genre

// Класс - компьютерная игра
public class Game
{
    [Key] // первичный ключ
    public int GameId { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; } // название игры

    // Жанр игры (внешний ключ на идентификатор игры)
    [ForeignKey("Genre")]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }

    // обладатель игры (внешний ключ на идентфикатор пользователя)
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    // Игра для взрослых: содержит ли кровь/сексуальный характер и прочее
    public bool IsAdult { get; set; }
}
```

Дальше с помощью шаблонов формирования пытаюсь создать grud операции: представления и действия в новом контролере.

**С классом Жанр "Genre" все получилось.**

При попытке создания шаблона формирования класса Game получаю ошибку:

> Не удалось извлечь метаданные для "MyWebApp.Models.Game"

**Заключение**: абсолютно уверен что трабл с полем "владелец игры", где внешний ключ на `ApplicationUser`. Как быть в такой ситуации? Нужно иметь игру с владельцем системы `Identity`.

Comment: А сколько у вас контекстов (`DbContext`): один или два? `Game` и `Genre` в том же контексте, что и `ApplicationUser`?

Comment: Один контекст дб. Да, в одном контексте.

Comment: А что если попробовать сначала сделать сборку проекта и только потом запустить генерацию?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в `ApplicationUser`, а точнее в аттрибуте `ForeignKey`. Удалите аттрибут `ForeignKey` и все заработает. EntityFramework автоматически определит ключ для класса `ApplicationUser`, когда он увидит этот класс - он добавит `ForeignKey` автоматически. Напишите код класса `Game` вот так:

```
public class Game
{
    [Key] 
    public int GameId { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }  

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdult { get; set; }
}
```

Для ознакомления: [DataAnnotations - ForeignKey Attribute](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: но ведь с логичной точки зрения логичнее использовать атрибут ForeignKey

Comment: @KDA, могу сказать, что есть определенные правила, которых нужно придерживаться. К использованию аттрибута имеет смысл прибегать лишь в случаях несовпадения имен (несоблюдения предписаний и рекомендаций по именованию свойств). К примеру в прошлом проекте, в котором я ранее работал и в текущем проекте у меня порядка пятиста таблиц, связанных между собой через внешние ключи, так вот, к использованию атттрибута `ForeignKey` в этих проектах мы прибегли всего несколько раз. Как раз логика и подсказывает, что проще именовать придерживаясь предписаний, чем дополнительно вешать аттрибуты :)